# Allow .htaccess to Subdirectory of a Blocked Directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi can I and how would I allow access to a directory named 'bDir' that is a subdirectory of 'aDir'?

In my .htaccess:

```
## Begin - Security
# Block all direct access for these folders
RewriteRule ^(aDir|bin|logs)/(.*) error [L]
. . .
```

In other words, the 'bDir' is in the 'aDir' and I need web access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
## Begin - Security
# Block all direct access for these folders
RewriteRule ^(aDir(?!/bDir)|bin|logs)/ error [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thnx! I assume to add additional directories in the "aDir", I would just use a pipe?

Comment: Yes that's right i.e. `RewriteRule ^(aDir(?!/(bDir|cDir|zdir))|bin|logs)/ error [L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare explicity the path for "bDir" before this rule.

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^aDir/bDir/(.*) /aDir/bDir/$1 [L]

## Begin - Security
# Block all direct access for these folders
RewriteRule ^(aDir|bin|logs)/(.*) error [L]
```